# CKEditor table data consume unwanted space in 4.x version

Tags: ckeditor4.x

How to trim the unwanted space in table data's up and down cell?
For your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the table to go into table properties and make sure you don't have padding set, or style option of line-height set. If those aren't wrong you can force the line-height with:

```
line-height:18px!important;
```

change 18px to the size that makes sense for the font size you are using.

It would really be best to figure out where that style is coming from instead though.